# Prevent element duplication without using std::vector and its features

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have a program that asks a user to enter ID and enter name. However, that ID must be unique so that the user can proceed to entering name, otherwise, the program must keep prompting the user to input a unique ID.

The problem is that albeit the user enters a unique string, the program still keeps prompting the user to enter ID, thus, the code for entering name never executes.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string ID = {};
    std::string copy[3] = {};
    std::string name = {};
    bool isDuplicated = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Enter details for student " << i + 1 << ": " << '\n';
        tryAgain:
        std::cout << "Enter ID: ";
        std::cin >> ID;

        // If ID is not duplicated,
        // continue to code of entering name. Otherwise,
        // keep prompting the user to enter a unique ID.

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            if (i != 0)
                copy[i] = ID;

            if (copy[i] == ID) {
                isDuplicated = true;
                std::cout << "ERROR" << '\n';
            }
        }

        if (isDuplicated)
            goto tryAgain;

        else {
            std::cout << "Enter name: ";
            std::cin >> name;
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Needed output (example simulation):

```
Enter details for student 1:
Enter ID: 13
Enter name: Dog

Enter details for student 2:
Enter ID: 13 
ERROR: You already entered the ID!
Enter ID again: 17    
Enter name: Cat

Enter details for student 3:
Enter ID: 21
Enter name: Mouse
```

What my program outputs:

```
Enter details for student 1:
Enter ID: 13
ERROR: You already entered the ID!
ERROR: You already entered the ID!
Enter ID: 17
ERROR: You already entered the ID!
ERROR: You already entered the ID!
```

Note that we cannot use std::vector and its features, the reason why we need to stick into our own written algorithm.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unrelated: `goto` is hard to get right. And if you do, it's even harder to convince people that it's right. It almost always takes less time to rewrite the code to use loops and plain old functions than it is to defend even the best of uses of `goto`. Here it looks like a `do`/`while` loop is an appropriate replacement.

Comment: even then, once you get it right and convince code review it is right, the code maintainer will either: hate you, or mess it up and cause bugs later on.

Comment: Try a code walk-through. Or step through it with a debugger. There are multiple issues related to your symptom (I spotted three reading the code; there might be more), which probably makes this question too broad for SO. When you step through the code, I would suggest initially focusing on why you get two "ERROR" lines per ID when your intent is to get only one.

Answer (score 2):

```
copy[i] = ID;
```

absolutely guarantees that

```
if (copy[i] == ID)
```

will find a duplicate.

Solution: Don't place `ID` into the array until AFTER verifying there are no duplicates.